# Произношение е/ё в молитве "Отче наш"

Tags: орфоэпия, славянизмы

Коллега-иностранка попросила наговорить для неё текст молитвы "Отче наш".
И я задумался: в конце надо говорить **ё** или **е**?

**...да святится имя Твое...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А это смотря на каком языке вы все это произносите.
Если на церковнославянском, то, конечно, тво**е**, никаких Ё.
Но это только каноническое произношение, обязательное лишь при проведении службы.

В быту давно произносят по-русски.
Надо ли посвящать во все тонкости иностранку - не знаю. Зависит не в последнюю очередь от её уровня владения русским. 
Думаю, что в среднестатистическом случае правильнее всего будет взять каноническое церковное произношение, но предупредить, что это далеко не современный русский.

Comment: Так и сделал. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Молитва не произносится на русском языке, такого перевода нет. Не приводя текст целиком, припомним некоторые места: ***на небесех; на небеси и на земли; да приидет...*** Определённо, не стоит лишь в одном слове допускать неточность. Хотя и страшного ничего не будет...

(PS) ...если вы не в православной церкви, где эта молитва как общая (Отче — наш!) наряду с Символом веры читается хором. Дать петуха в храме не позволит себе любой разумный человек, даже если знает место из Евангелия, которое стало её основой.

Comment: Еще как произносится. http://www.katolik.ru/bogosluzhenie/molitvy/item/2626-molitva-otche-nash-tekst.html

Comment: «подавай нам на каждый день?» В РПЦ так не говорят. Это пересказ, а не перевод.

Comment: А при чем тут РПЦ? Хотите у РПЦ удостиовериться - держите синодальній перевод. http://days.pravoslavie.ru/Bible/Index.htm

Comment: Вот точная ссылка на "пересказ". http://days.pravoslavie.ru/Bible/B_lk11.htm - один в один, как у и католиков.

Answer (score 1):

Если молитва  на русском язык, то *твоё*. Если текст на церковнославянском, то там е в ё никогда не превращается, поэтому *твое*.